# Hide location context in intellij 2016.2?

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't seem to figure out how to hide the location context of where the cursor is. For example:

[image]

I don't really care about this information and its taking up screen real estate

Comment: Ok, turns out its just disabling breadcrumbs via Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance